# Select particular part of string from table

Tags: mysql

I have one table. In that I am storing user details there like firstname, lastname, phonenumber. while storing phone number it stores data without extension like **+1(013)691-1535x_*_*_** . Sometime user might enter extension also that it will store like **+1(013)691-1535x12345**. Here my doubt is how to retrieve only phone number if extension is in empty. If extension is avaiable I need to view phone number with extension.

Comment: did you store extension in separated column

Comment: No I am storing in same column.

Comment: followed by X you should be stored the value of extension ah

Comment: Yes. I am storing extension followed by X

Answer (score 2):

You can split the phone number using [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php) :

```
SELECT phone_number,SUBSTRING_INDEX(phone_number, 'x', 1) as phone_num, SUBSTRING_INDEX(phone_number, 'x', -1) as phone_ext FROM tablename;
```

**Query result**

```
+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| phone_number          | phone_num       | phone_ext |
+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| +1(013)691-1535x12345 | +1(013)691-1535 | 12345     |
+-----------------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

Now, you have  entire phone number with extension, phone number without extension and only extension. Depending on the query result, you can have a 'check' in your script and use the field value.

Comment: I have to see both in the same result. if extension is available it should show, otherwise no need . I donot want results in splited columns. thanks

Answer (score 1):

try like or  Well if you know the order of your words.. you can use REGEXP

```
  SELECT `phone_number` FROM `table` WHERE `phone_number` LIKE '+1(013)691-1535x%'
```